# OpenCL matrix multiplication on Mathematica

Tags: opencllink

I took a matrix multiplication written using OpenCL from [here](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/opencl-tutorial/case-study-matrix-multiplication/):

```
src = "__kernel void
floatMatrixMult(__global float * MResp,
                __global float * M1,
                __global float * M2,
                __global int * q)
   {
    // Vector element index
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    int p = get_global_size(0);
    int r = get_global_size(1);
    MResp[i + p * j] = 0;
    int QQ = q[0];
    for (int k = 0; k < QQ; k++)
    {
        MResp[i + p * j] += M1[i + p * k] * M2[k + QQ * j];
    }
}";
```

then I used:

```
test = OpenCLFunctionLoad[{src}, "floatMatrixMult", {"Float", "Float", "Float", _Integer}, {8, 8}];
```

but I get this error:

> OpenCLFunctionLoad::nofile: -- Message text not found -- (*contents of* `src`) >>

There isn't any documents to explain this. How can I resolve the issue? If the code itself has problem are there some other codes to do matrix multiplication using OpenCL?

Comment: The documentation you're looking for is the `OpenCLFunctionLoad` help page. Your call to it is completely wrong.

Comment: Also, there is a matrix-matrix multiplication example in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"]

test = OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, "floatMatrixMult", {
    {"Float", 2, "Output"},
    {"Float", 2, "Input"}, {"Float", 2, "Input"}, {_Integer, 1, "Input"}
   },
   {16, 16}
  ];

SIZE = 1024;

a = RandomReal[1, {SIZE, SIZE}];
m1 = OpenCLMemoryLoad[a, "Float"];

b = RandomReal[10, {SIZE, SIZE}];
m2 = OpenCLMemoryLoad[b, "Float"];

out = OpenCLMemoryAllocate["Float", {SIZE, SIZE}];

test[out, m2, m1, {SIZE, SIZE}];

Norm[OpenCLMemoryGet[out] - a.b]
(* -> 0.0809831 *)
```